# Creating a shape inside of an image trace in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How can I create a shape using the pen tool inside of a logo I traced? I am trying to make the airplane in this vector file a different color from the rest of the A. Everything I am doing with the pen tool or Path -> Join does not seem to isolate the airplane shape. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you merely want to color the inside areas of the plane.... (Your question isn't clear).

First, you must **Expand** the trace by clicking the <kbd>EXPAND</kbd> button on the control bar across the top of the screen.

---

If you **did NOT** choose the `Ignore white` option when tracing....

Merely use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) to click the plane and change the fill color....

[image]

---

If you **DID** choose the `Ignore White` option when tracing...

Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow), and hold down the **<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key** and click the **path** around the inner area. Once *only* that path is selected choose `Edit > Cut`. If the middle is *still* white. Do it again.. until the center of the plane fills in with the red color.

Then, still using the **Direct Selection Tool**, click the red area of the plane and choose `Edit > Paste In Front` from the menu. You'll see the shape appear, but it'll be red. merely change it's fill color now.....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should redraw the inner shape using the **Pencil** and the **Pen Tool** in a duplicate to isolate the plane.

- Use the **Pencil** and make a line following the bottom side of each wing to eliminate the parts below.
- Use the **Pen Tool** to eliminate the surplus vector points

[image: wings 1]

- Select the image and make the same with the top part
- Use the **Direct Selection Tool** to move up the top points outside the plane and delete them

[image: wings 2]

- Select the top point and delete it
- Use the **Direct Selection Tool** to select the top left points and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> Win to join them
- Do the same with the right points

[image: top part]

- Put this shape on top of the original and change the color

[image: end]